# How to modify Ranking criteria to specify a cutoff date

Tags: r

I have this code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
top5vio <- inc_ag %>%
  mutate(Zone=ifelse(ZoneID=="Outside ZoneZ", 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, Zone) %>%
  mutate(grp=factor(+(min_rank(desc(violentIncidents))<=5) + Zone,
                    labels=c("Top 5", "Rest of Zones", "Outside Zones"),
                    levels=c(1,0,2))) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, grp) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(violentIncidents)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=grp, values_from=n, values_fill=list(n=0))
```

This makes a grouping variable (grp) equal to 1 if the violentIncidents variable is in the top 5 and 0 otherwise. Then it combines this with those that have ZonedID = "Outside Zones" to create 3 groups.

However, what if I want to establish the top 5 rank as of a given date (say 6/20/2019), and that the zoneIDs selected must be the top 5 as of 6/20/2019? What would be the appropriate syntax?

Thank you.

The code transforms the following data:

```
obs District    ZoneID  Period  violentIncidents
1   Northwestern    Northern: 53A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 4
2   Northwestern    Northern: 53B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 0
3   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 88
4   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 44
5   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 212
6   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 38
7   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 18
8   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62C   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 65
9   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 4
10  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 107
11  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 19
12  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63C   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 56
13  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 165
14  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATA  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 28
15  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATB  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 26
16  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATC  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 114
17  Northwestern    Outside Zones 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06   1501
18  Southern    Outside Zones 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06   2062
19  Southwestern Outside Zones  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 1351
```

Into this:

```
  District     Period                  `Top 5` `Rest of Zones` `Outside Zones`
  <chr>        <chr>                     <int>           <int>           <int>
1 Northwestern 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06     686             302            1501
2 Southern     2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06       0               0            2062
3 Southwestern 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06       0               0            1351
```

Comment: All of your example data have the same dates, making it challenging to answer your question, consider editing with some dates before and after 2019-06-20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this approach with `lubridate` may work for you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
inc_ag %>%
  mutate(Zone=ifelse(ZoneID=="Outside Zones", 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(PeriodSplit = Period) %>% 
  separate(col = PeriodSplit,into=c("periodStart","periodEnd"),sep = " - ") %>%
  filter(periodEnd <= ymd("2019-06-20")) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, Zone) %>%
  mutate(grp=factor(+(min_rank(desc(violentIncidents))<=5) + Zone,
                    labels=c("Top 5", "Rest of Zones", "Outside Zones"),
                    levels=c(1,0,2))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(District,ZoneID,grp) %>%
  right_join(inc_ag,by=c("District","ZoneID")) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, grp) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(violentIncidents)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=grp, values_from=n, values_fill=list(n=0))
```